# rviz: undefined symbol

Tags: rviz, ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After upgrading today:

> rosrun rviz rviz
> /home/dereck/Dropbox/ros/hydro/catkin/devel/lib/rviz/rviz:
> symbol lookup error:
> /home/dereck/Dropbox/ros/hydro/catkin/devel/lib/librviz.so:
> undefined symbol:
> _ZN3ros7console5printEPNS0_10FilterBaseEPN7log4cxx6LoggerENS0_6levels5LevelEPKciS9_S9_z

any thoughts?

Ubuntu 13.04 & hydro

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/126146/rviz:-undefined-symbol/) by [Dereck](https://answers.ros.org/users/2254/dereck/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1070 on 2014-02-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ah... I appear to have had an old version of rviz laying around in a catkin workspace's devel folder. rm'd it and i'm back in action. :)

---

Originally posted by [Dereck](https://answers.ros.org/users/2254/dereck/) with karma: 1070 on 2014-02-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0